# How genetic algorithm is different from random selection and evaluation for fittest?

Tags: random, selection, genetic-algorithm

I have been learning the genetic algorithm since 2 months. I knew about the process of initial population creation, selection , crossover and mutation etc. But could not understand how we are able to get better results in each generation and how its different than random search for a best solution. Following I am using one example to explain my problem.

Lets take example of travelling salesman problem. Lets say we have several cities as X1,X2....X18 and we have to find the shortest path to travel. So when we do the crossover after selecting the fittest guys, how do we know that after crossover we will get a better chromosome. The same applies for mutation also.

I feel like its just take one arrangement of cities. Calculate the shortest distance to travel them. Then store the distance and arrangement. Then choose another another arrangement/combination. If it is better than prev arrangement, then save the current arrangement/combination and distance else discard the current arrangement. By doing this also, we will get some solution.

I just want to know where is the point where it makes the difference between random selection and genetic algorithm. In genetic algorithm, is there any criteria that we can't select the arrangement/combination of cities which we have already evaluated?

I am not sure if my question is clear. But I am open, I can explain more on my question. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A random algorithm starts with a completely blank sheet every time.  A new random solution is generated each iteration, with no memory of what happened before during the previous iterations.

A genetic algorithm has a history, so it does not start with a blank sheet, except at the very beginning.  Each generation the best of the solution population are selected, mutated in some way, and advanced to the next generation.  The least good members of the population are dropped.

Genetic algorithms build on previous success, so they are able to advance faster than random algorithms.  A classic example of a very simple genetic algorithm, is the [Weasel program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program).  It finds its target far more quickly than random chance because each generation it starts with a partial solution, and over time those initial partial solutions are closer to the required solution.

Comment: In general it is not true that best solutions are selected. It usually  is a random process that prefers better solutions, certainly not always guarantees it.

Comment: @luk32 The "best" solutions are those that score highest in the evaluation algorithm used to sort the population once each generation.  That algorithm might include a random element, for example a tournament round.  Better solutions will have a higher chance of their offspring making it into the next generation.

Comment: Yes of course, but only elitarism *guareantees* that best will survive, rest is odds. Better solutions have higher chance, but not certainty, which I believe you implied in your answer. Selection is not sorting, its a stochastic process not deterministic. IMO it's important to stress it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things you are asking about. A mathematical proof that GA works, and empirical one, that would waive your concerns.

Although I am not aware if there is general proof, I am quite sure at least a good sketch of a proof was given by John Holland in his book *Adaptation in Natural and Artificial Systems* for the optimization problems using binary coding. There is something called [Holland's schemata theoerm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holland%27s_schema_theorem). But you know, it's heuristics, so technically it does not have to be. It basically says that short schemes in genotype raising the average fitness appear exponentially with successive generations. Then cross-over combines them together. I think the proof was given only for binary coding and got some criticism as well.

Regarding your concerns. Of course you have no guarantee that a cross-over will produce a better result. As two intelligent or beautiful parents might have ugly stupid children. The premise of GA is that it is less likely to happen. (As I understand it) The proof for binary coding hinges on the theoerm that says a good partial patterns will start emerging, and given that the length of the genotype should be long enough, such patterns residing in different specimen have chance to be combined into one improving his fitness in general.

I think it is fairly easy to understand in terms of TSP. Crossing-over help to accumulate good sub-paths into one specimen. Of course it all depends on the choice of the crossing method.

Also GA's path towards the solution is not purely random. It moves towards a certain direction with stochastic mechanisms to escape trappings. You *can* lose best solutions if you allow it. It works because it wants to move towards the current best solutions, but you have a population of specimens and they kind of share knowledge. They are all similar, but given that you preserve diversity new better partial patterns can be introduced to the whole population and get incorporated into the best solutions. This is why diversity in population is regarded as very important.

As a final note please remember the GA is a very broad topic and you can modify the base in nearly every way you want. You can introduce elitarism, taboos, niches, etc. There is no one-and-only approach/implementation.